# Tooltip directive content not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have this HTML:

```
<span ng-show="!viewingOwnProfile() && user.isOnline == false" class="offline" tooltip data-content="Last seen {{user.lastSeenDateTime}}"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></span>
```

basically the data-content is the content to be shown in the tooltip. But it shows "Last seen  {{user.lastSeenDateTime}}" inside tooltip instead of showing the actual datetime.

This is my directive.

```
angApp.directive('tooltip', function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            console.log(attrs);
            $(elem).poshytip({
                className: 'tip-twitter',
                alignTo: 'target',
                alignX: 'right',
                alignY: 'center',
                offsetX: 5,
                offsetY: 5,
                fade: false,
                slide: false,
                content: $(elem).data('content')
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I am using poshytip to show the tooltip. Please let me know how can I fix this such that it would work even with static text and even with dynamic `{{}}` expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call $observe to watch for changes to an interpolated string:

```
angApp.directive('tooltip', function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            console.log(attrs);

            // watch for changes to content attribute.
            attrs.$observe(attrs.content, function(newVal) {
                if (newVal) {
                   elem.poshytip({
                       className: 'tip-twitter',
                       alignTo: 'target',
                       alignX: 'right',
                       alignY: 'center',
                       offsetX: 5,
                       offsetY: 5,
                       fade: false,
                       slide: false,
                       content: newVal                
                   });
                }
            });

        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work. I get this error: TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: I was missing some curlies - try again?

Comment: it was almost perfect except it should be attrs.$observe not scope.$observe.

Comment: oops, thanks for the correction. I'll update my answer